# Update table in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am just learning R. I have a small project where a timetable is displayed and the user has the possibility to enter a subject.
My problem: I do not know how to enter a subject (for example "math") in the timetable (dataframe). As soon as the user presses the action button, the subject should be entered in the table at the position ["1", "monday"].

I tried it here by:

```
output$my_table <- renderDataTable(df())

  df <- eventReactive(input$button, {
    timetable["1", "monday"] <- input$select1
  })
```

which unfortunately does not work. Any tips and advice on how I can enter something into a table would be greatly appreciated!

This is my Code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
  titlePanel(h1("My timetable", align = "center" )),
  sidebarLayout(
    position = c("left"),
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 4,
      selectInput("select1", label = h5("Event:"),
                  choices = c("math" , "sience", "sport") ,
                  selected = 1,
                  width = 400),
      actionButton("action", label = "Add")),
    mainPanel(
      width = 8,
      tableOutput('my_table')),
  ),
)
```

and the server:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$my_table = renderTable({timetable<- data.frame(monday <- c("","","","",""),
                                                        tuesday <- c("","","","",""),
                                                        wednesday <- c("","","","",""),
                                                        thursday <- c("","","","",""),  
                                                        friday <- c("","","","",""))}, 
                                bordered = TRUE, 
                                spacing = c('l'), 
                                width = "100%",
                                striped = TRUE,
                                align = 'c',
                                rownames = TRUE)
  
  output$timetable <- renderDataTable(df())
  
  df <- eventReactive(input$action, { timetable["1","monday"] <- input$select1 })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete working example that may be helpful.

First, I might define a separate `reactiveVal` to store your data.frame. This will be accessible in both your table output as well as either `observeEvent` or `eventReactive` methods.

When you reference your `reactiveVal`, use `timetable()` with parentheses at the end. When you want to replace the data.frame stored in `timetable`, you can do `timetable(new_data_frame_here)`. In the `observeEvent`, I created a temporary `tmp` data.frame that can be used to edit further for convenience.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
  titlePanel(h1("My timetable", align = "center" )),
  sidebarLayout(
    position = c("left"),
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 4,
      selectInput("select1", label = h5("Event:"),
                  choices = c("math" , "sience", "sport") ,
                  selected = 1,
                  width = 400),
      actionButton("action", label = "Add")),
    mainPanel(
      width = 8,
      tableOutput('my_table')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  timetable <- reactiveVal(
    data.frame(monday = c("","","","",""),
               tuesday = c("","","","",""),
               wednesday = c("","","","",""),
               thursday = c("","","","",""),
               friday = c("","","","",""))
  )
   
  output$my_table = renderTable(timetable(),
                                bordered = TRUE,
                                spacing = c('l'),
                                width = "100%",
                                striped = TRUE,
                                align = 'c',
                                rownames = TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$action, { 
    tmp <- timetable()
    tmp[1, "monday"] <- input$select1
    timetable(tmp)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help!
My actual code is a little more detailed, but I was able to apply it to him as well. It works now. :)
There is one more question. Assuming the subject math was entered in the timetable. Is there a possibility to click on this field in the dataframe, for example to output a modal dialog like it would be possible with an actionbutton?